# iOS Virtual Tours engine

Tags: ios, html, virtual-tour

I'm looking for a solution how to create offline 3D virtual tour app for iOS. Are there any engines or libraries, that can help?
I need the support of hotspots and audiofiles.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course.

http://www.easypano.com/virtual-tour-software.html

Starting from 199.95 USD.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I'll have a look.